# How does one calculate the polarization state of random light after total internal reflection

Tags: optics, reflection, polarization

How does one calculate the polarization state of random light after having been totally reflected by a single dielectric interface? Please consider pure specular reflexions from a plane interface between two dielectric mediums of indexes $n_1,\,n_2$ when the angle of incidence $\theta_1$ is greater than the critical angle $\arcsin(n_2/n_1)$.

Comment: I think you wrote it quite well. By the way, you are like the optics lord here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll stick to pure total internal, specular reflexion in this answer.

When TIR happens, both linear polarisation components are fully relfected, but the phase change (the Goos-Hänchen shift) is different for the two states. In scalar theory the [Goos-Hänchen shift (see my answer here)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/89986/26076) for the two states, but the full vector theory shows a subtle difference. What this means practically is that the two polarisation states seem to reflect from ever so slightly different depths *into* the denser medium beyond the totally internally reflecting interface.

The Fresnel equations still apply in this situation. Now, of course, we get $\sin\theta_t>1$ so that $\cos\theta_t = \sqrt{1-\sin\theta_t^2}$ is imaginary. We interpret the trigonometric functions exactly as they are interpreted in the derivation of the Fresnel equations (*e.g.* in Reference [1]), to wit, the sine and cosine are the ratios $k_x/k$ and $k_z/k$ of the wavevector components tangential and normal to the interface, respectively. The cosine is imaginary beyond the interface, so the wave is *evanescent* and exponentially decaying with depth as in [my answer cited above](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/89986/26076).  So, from the Fresnel equations:

$$r_s = \frac{n_1 \cos \theta_i - n_2 \cos \theta_t}{n_1 \cos \theta_i + n_2 \cos \theta_t} = \frac{n_1 c_1 - i\, n_2 c_2}{n_1 c_1 + i\,n_2 c_2}$$

$$t_s = \frac{2 n_1 \cos \theta_i}{n_1 \cos \theta_i + n_2 \cos \theta_t}= \frac{2 n_1 c_1}{n_1 c_1 + i\,n_2 c_2}$$

$$r_p = \frac{n_2 \cos \theta_i - n_1 \cos \theta_\text{t}}{n_1 \cos \theta_t + n_2 \cos \theta_i} = \frac{n_2 c_1 -i\,  n_1 c_2}{n_1 c_2 + i\, n_2 c_1} = -i$$

$$t_p = \frac{2 n_1\cos \theta_i}{n_1 \cos \theta_t + n_2 \cos \theta_i}= \frac{2 n_1 c_1}{n_1 c_2 + i\,n_2 c_1}\tag{1}$$

where $c_1 = \cos\theta_1$ and $c_2 = \text{Im}(\cos\theta_2)$ are both real numbers. Take heed that the reflexion co-efficients are either a complex numbers of the form $r_s=z^*/z$ or $r_p = -i$ and thus have unity magnitude, so all the power is reflected. The Goos-Hänchen shifts for the two orthogonal linear polarisations are:

$$\phi_s = -2\,\arg(n_1 c_1 + i\,n_2 c_2) = -2\,\arctan\left(\frac{n_2 c_2}{n_1 c_1}\right)$$

$$\phi_p = -\frac{\pi}{2}\tag{2}$$

which are almost equal in most cases: they deviate more significantly from one another for highly glancing angles $\theta_1\approx\pi/2$ (which condition invalidates the scalar theory of [my other answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/89986/26076)).

In particular, as the incidence angle approaches $\pi/2$ and the reflexion becomes highly grazing, $\phi_s\to-\pi$ and $\phi_p\to-\pi/2$. That is, the TIR mechanism mimics a quarter wave plate.

So, for your random polarisation, you are going to either represent it as a known, pure polarisation with a $2\times1$ Jones vector $X = \left(\begin{array}{c}x_p\\x_s\end{array}\right)$ and transform it by:

$$X\mapsto U\,X;\;\text{where}\;U = \left(\begin{array}{cc}e^{i\,\phi_p}&0\\0&e^{i\,\phi_s}\end{array}\right)$$

or if the light is depolarised (a mixed state) you will use the Mueller calculus / density matrix formalism:

$$\rho\mapsto U\,\rho\,U^\dagger;\;\text{where}\;\rho = \sum\limits_{j=0}^3 s_j \sigma_j$$

$\sigma_0 = {\rm id}$ is the $2\times 2$ identity matrix, $\sigma_j$ the Pauli spin matrice and the co-efficients $s_j$ are the four Stokes parameters as described in [my answer on dealing with calculations with depolarised light](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/92176/26076).

Reference:

[1] §1.5 "Reflexion and Refraction of a Plane Wave" in the seventh edition of Born and Wolf, "Principles of Optics".