# What causes the circular polarization of light from outside Snell's window?

Tags: optics, water, reflection, refraction, polarization

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_polarization) and [other sources](http://sites.sinauer.com/animalcommunication2e/chapter05.02.html) claim that the internal reflection underwater outside Snell's window is circularly polarized.  What is the mechanism that causes this circular polarization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim is true only for the following conditions:

1. Reflexion that is *highly grazing*, *i.e.* the incident wave is almost parallel to the interface and the angle of incidence approaches $\pi/2$;
2. The incident light is linearly polarized and the plane of polarization is exactly halfway between the $s$ and $p$ polarization planes, *i.e.* so that the electric field makes an angle of $45^\circ$ with the intersection line between the transverse plane of propagation and the interface.

In short, at glancing angles, the TIR mechanism mimics the action of a quarter wave plate.

I show the above is true with the Fresnel equations in [my answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/92923/26076) to the Physics SE question [How does one calculate the polarization state of random light after total internal reflection](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/92874/26076) (read the answer to about halfway, where I discuss the grazing angle case).

The mechanism is that the [Goos-Hänchen phase shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goos%E2%80%93H%C3%A4nchen_effect) differs for the $s$ and $p$ states. It is a little hard to give an intuitive explanation; one has to refer to the Fresnel equations (as I do [in my answer referred to above](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/92923/26076)). But remember that TIR doesn't happen at the interface; the field tunnels beyond the interface a small distance as an evanescent field, as I [explain in my answer here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/89986/26076). So it is intuitively clear that there is an *effective* plane of reflexion a small distance beyond the physical interface owing to the nonzero tunnelling *i.e.* turnaround distance, and this distance happens to be a quarter of a wavelength at highly glancing incidence angles.