# What is the difference between the Franz-Keldysh effect and free carrier absorption?

Tags: optics, semiconductor-physics

What is the difference between the [Franz-Keldysh effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franz%E2%80%93Keldysh_effect) and free carrier absorption? My first guess to this is that the Franz-Keldysh effect involves a bandgap potential of non-zero volts D.C. while the free carrier absorption effect involves a bandgap potential of zero volts. Obviously, this distinction is very simplistic and I was hoping someone could discuss about this topic.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "free carrier absorption" I think *intra-band* transitions.  These transitions do not conserve crystal momentum, so they must occur somewhere where translational symmetry is broken.  An example of such a place is the region near near the surface of a semiconductor where the bands are bent, or when an electric field is present.

The Franz-Keldysh effect involves *inter-band* transitions, also occurring where the bands are tilted (possibly due to an electric field), but momentum in this case *is* conserved. The transitions occur between the tails of the electron wavefunction that tunnel into the (tilted) forbidden gap.   The F-K effect is sometimes called *tunneling-assisted absorption*.

See also an [answer I gave to a related question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/107272/5739).