# Meaning of wave function which is in inside of the potential wall?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, potential, probability, quantum-tunneling

In particle in square potential barrier problem, we can easily find that some probabilities exist which express how many particles can go beyond of the potential wall.

So my question is that, can we find some particles in the potential wall - square of wave function's norm really means  probability of find a particle in the wall?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11188/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 0):

> In particle in square potential barrier problem, we can easily find that some probabilities exist which express how many particles can go beyond of the potential wall.

As there may be a language problem here, there are two interpretations of your question.

1) the [barrier problem](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/qmech/Quantum/node48.html) which allows for [tunneling](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/barr.html)

2) The [square well potential](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/nuclear-engineering/22-02-introduction-to-applied-nuclear-physics-spring-2012/lecture-notes/MIT22_02S12_lec_ch4.pdf) which will give energy levels for occupation

> So my question is that, can we find some particles in the potential wall - square of wave function's norm really means probability of find a particle in the wall?

Answering 1), the answer is yes.

[image: tunneling]

It is called tunneling, and there is a quantum mechanical probability for the particle to exist beyond  the barrier.

Answering 2) [the link given by Qmecanic](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/11188/can-a-particle-be-physically-observed-inside-a-quantum-barrier) has a number of relevant answers . which also say yes for a potential well if the energy of the particle is an energy level of the well and is unoccupied.